# Fixedpoints of involution of field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Suppose we have a field extension $L | K$ and a nontrivial $K$-automorphism $\phi: L \rightarrow L$, ie. an automorphism on $L$ which fixes the elements of $K$, which is an involution, ie. selfinverse. What conditions do we have to impose on $L$ or $\phi$ to have that $\phi(x)=x \Rightarrow x \in K$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim.** The extension $L/L^{\langle \phi\rangle}$ has degree $2$.

Since $L^{\langle \phi\rangle}$ contains $K$, we deduce immediately that $L^{\langle \phi\rangle}=K$ if and only if $L/K$ has degree $2$.

**Proof of the claim.**

This follows directly from Artin's lemma, which says that  $L/L^{\langle \phi\rangle}$ is in fact Galois of degree $2$, but we do not need the galois property, and there is a direct way to compute the degree, which I give now.

Let $E=L^{\langle \phi\rangle}$.
Let $\alpha\in L^\times$ such that $\phi(\alpha)\neq \alpha$. I claim that $1,\alpha$ is an $E$-basis of $L$.

First, they are $E$-linearly independent, since otherwise $\alpha\in E$.

Now let $x\in L$, and set $b=(\phi(x)-x)(\phi(\alpha)-\alpha)^{-1}$, and $a=x-b\alpha$.

Then $\phi(b)=b$ (this uses that $\phi$ is an automorphism satisying $\phi\circ\phi=\phi$). Moreover, $\phi(a)=\phi(x)-b\phi(\alpha)$, so $\phi(a)-a=\phi(x)-x-b(\phi(\alpha)-\alpha)=0$ by definition of $b$. Hence $a,b,\in E$. Now ,by definition of $a$, $x=a+b\alpha$, and we are done.

Comment: Thank you very much! I assume $L^{\langle \phi \rangle$ is the subfield of fixed points of $\phi$, right? I don’t quite see, why the extension $L | L^{\phi}$ is Galois. I don’t have access to my lecture notes on Galoistheory, which was ages ago, so could you please give a hint?

Comment: Yes, that's it. It is simply Artin's lemma: if $L$ is a field, and $G$ is a finite group of ring automomorphisms of $L$, then $L/L^G$ is Galois, with Galois group $G$. This is a nontrivial result, a bit tricky to show.  In fact you do not need the fact it is Galois, just the fact that the degree of the fixed field is $2$. I will added a direct proof later.

Comment: Thank you very much!